# Webpage crashing on any web browser for iOS device

Tags: ios, google-chrome, safari, html, magento2

I am trying to access webpage on various browser on iOS Device, but it seems that after loading some part of the webpage, it redirects automatically and then crash the page and shows `the webpage was reloaded because a problem occurred` for 2 seconds, and then show `A problem repeatedly occurred on "URL for page as below"`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this URL on a desktop and it was not behaving well.  I don't know if it is there rotating image code, or the JavaScript code they have running the "design your shoe" features.  But this site had weird stops and starts and mouse jumps when I tried it.

I don't have an iOS device handy, but I'm thinking it is not you, it's the site.

Try it on another device.

Comment: I think you are wrong....  Now in 2021, iOS is still broken, seems to be related to CSS and affects Chrome and Safari.